# C# 11, Raw String Literals - Line does not start with the same whitespace as the closing line

Tags: c#, string, string-literals, c#-11.0

Trying to use the newly introduced C# 11 feature **Raw string literals**, as you can see in the following example:

```cs
_logger.LogCritical($"""
    
new value: {value}
computed new value :   {value / 100}
old value:  {UwpMediaPlayer.Volume}
    
 """);
```

leads to the following error:

> Line does not start with the same whitespace as the closing line of
> the raw string literal

My goal is to figure out how this feature should be used and what is wrong with the code that I have currently written.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and for any help you can provide.

Comment: You have an extraneous space character right before your closing triple-quotes.

Comment: …if that doesn’t fix it, turn-on Visible Whitespace and ensure you’re using consistent indentation (i.e. _only_ using either 4-spaces or only using `\t` (as God intended) in your files).

Comment: Is this addressed?

Answer (score 5):

C# 11 raw string have some rules to use this feature, here are those rules we need to follow :-

1. Spacing is very important, starting and ending 3 double quotes should start and end at the same level/space please find the below image for better visibility.

[image]

2. Ending 3 double quotes would be illegal/will throw error if you try to end quotes ahead of starting 3 double quotes

[image]

3. However, you can still end the 3 doubles quotes before the same space, C# 11 compiler would still be happy.

[image]

4. It can't be ended right after the content

[image]

Summary :

C# 11 string Literal is very jealous  guy, it can't see anyone to go beoynd him. He is happy if someone stay behind him or on same level but if someone try to grow/go ahead of him, he start crying.

I have created this video in detail, if my text still does not make sense. Please feel free to watch video, I have covered all the rules and concepts that we should know while working with C# 11 string literals.

https://youtu.be/itr3e6KkR0I

Answer (score 1):

I am able to compile by just changing from

```
_logger.LogCritical($"""
    
new value: {value}
computed new value :   {value / 100}
old value:  {UwpMediaPlayer.Volume}
    
 """)
```

to

```
_logger.LogCritical($"""
    
new value: {value}
computed new value :   {value / 100}
old value:  {UwpMediaPlayer.Volume}
    
""").
```

I have just removed the space before the closing `"""`.