# How to fix Visual Studio "bad compile constant value" error when using the C# 11 Raw String Literals feature?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm writing a test method that appears to be reasonable to have a JSON value attributed to a variable. I decided to use the C# 11 Raw String Literals feature to improve the code readability. The thing is Visual Studio still complaining about the usage of this feature and returning the "bad compile constant value" error.

[image]

The above value was copied from the Microsoft Docs [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)

Info regarding the project:
It's a C# NUnit test project.
I'm using .NET 6 which I know uses C#10 as the default language (as we can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)).
So, using Directory.build.props as directives to build the projects I added to the root build.props file the following line:

`<LangVersion>11.0</LangVersion>`

The projects in the whole solution compile even using Visual Studio IDE or with the dotnet build command line (and also the tests are passing).

How to fix that?

I tried to determine the default language for the project using visual studio project properties (and it looks like ok).

[image: project build properties]

I also tried the indentation thing as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75825615/3434514

I'm expecting to Visual Studio recognize the usage of the usage of """ Raw string literals declaration.

Comment: You might  need to close VS then delete the bin, obj and .vs folders and then restart VS and reload the project.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem. I tried it, thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the latest version of JetBrains ReSharper installed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."